# Angular 9: I've a problem with mat-tab-group in material-angular

Tags: angular-material, angular9

I used a [@kolkov/angular-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kolkov/angular-editor) text module which should allow me to edit my texts and my wish is to use it on both parts.
Except that there is a problem that I cannot find a solution.

If you can help me find the solution.

```html
<mat-card>
       <div class="help-container">
         <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs class="bko-stretched-tabs mat-elevation-z4">
            <mat-tab label="Tutorials">
                <backoffice-tutorials></backoffice-tutorials>
                tab1
            </mat-tab>
    
            <mat-tab label="Support">
                <backoffice-support></backoffice-support>
                tab2
            </mat-tab>
         </mat-tab-group>
       </div>
    </mat-card>
```

[image]

here we see that in `tab2` nothing is even displayed the plain text `tab2` in the html.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `<ng-template>` inside `<mat-tab>`, like this:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs class="bko-stretched-tabs mat-elevation-z4">
     <mat-tab label="Tutorials">
       <ng-template matTabContent>
         <backoffice-tutorials></backoffice-tutorials>
          tab1
       </ng-template>
     </mat-tab>
    
     <mat-tab label="Support">
       <ng-template matTabContent>
         <backoffice-support></backoffice-support>
          tab2
       </ng-template>
     </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: I had tested to put **ng-template** at the level of mat-tab "support" only but the problem persists despite the addition.
even when i inspect the item i don't see anything it looks like it removes it on display